# Mathematica Notebook Navigation Shortcuts

Tags: navigation, wolfram-mathematica, shortcut

I really enjoy structuring my Notebook with different part & sub-parts, however, I have not yet found the shortcuts to navigate it efficiently.

For example :

-How to go from one paragraph to another ?
-From a cell to another ?
-"Open" or "Expend" a paragraph or

Many thank in advance,

LA

Comment: My apologies, will not post such questions again, I respect this rule.

Comment: @500 You still may ask this question on [superuser.com](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mathematica).

Comment: @500 Take a look at http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/KeyboardShortcutListing.html

Comment: @belisarius @Alexey I don't think this is off-topic. The question is about the notebook interface, which is Mathematica's IDE. Therefore it is within the scope mentioned in the faq (software tools commonly used by programmers). Vote for reopen.

Comment: I agree with @Sjoerd: It's on-topic.